# ブラウザで npmモジュールを使用したいが、require が使えない

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify

ブラウザで[npmモジュール](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone)を使用するには、どうすれば良いでしょうか。

・動作確認したいコード（`main.js`）

```
var clone = require('clone');

var a, b;

a = { foo: { bar: 'baz' } };  // initial value of a 

b = clone(a);                 // clone a -> b 
a.foo.bar = 'foo';            // change a 

console.log(a);               // show a 
console.log(b);
```

ブラウザで上記コードを実行したら、下記エラーとなりました。

> `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

・上記コードを `main.js` として保存後、下記コマンドを実行した後、

```
npm install clone
npm install -g browserify
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

・出力されたbundle.jsを読み込んだら、望む結果を取得できました
・毎回このような処理が必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: 「var clone = require('clone')」したら表示されました

Comment: <script src="main.js"> と書いて ブラウザ実行しました。(ポート番号指定したくないため、)普通のブラウザで実行したいのですが…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` は Node.js 特有の関数です。ブラウザには用意されていません。

`require` のようなモジュール機構を標準の仕様として策定する試みは進んでおり、[`import` 文](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)として形になっていますが、まだ各ブラウザでそのまま使える状態ではありません。
よって、モジュールとして提供されているコードをブラウザで使う方法も標準と言えるような物はなく、各々の好みや必要に応じてツールや作業手順を選ぶ事になります。

### npm モジュールの Node.js での利用

Node.js では `require` が使えますので、質問のコード（`main.js`）はそのまま動きます。
`npm` コマンドが使える環境でしたら `node` もあると思いますので、以下のようにします。

```sh
node main.js
# 出力:
# { foo: { bar: 'foo' } }
# { foo: { bar: 'baz' } }
```

### ブラウザでの利用

`npm` で配布されているパッケージの中にはブラウザでは動かない物もありますので、そこは確認が必要です。
また、ブラウザで動かす際はプロジェクトページや README に方法の記述があれば、まずはそれに従うのが無難でしょう。

例えば以下のような方法があります。

#### `<script>` で個別に読み込む

clone モジュールは単一のファイルなので、以下のようになります。

```html
<script src="clone.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

[`clone.js`](https://github.com/pvorb/node-clone/blob/master/clone.js) は下記のようにグローバル変数 `clone` を先頭で宣言しています。

```ja
var clone = (function() {
```

ですから、`main.js` ではこの変数を使えます。
`require` している部分は削除します。
もちろん、`clone.js` をしかるべき場所に配置しておく必要があります。

#### JavaScript のファイルを結合する

専用のツールなどもありますが、要するにファイルをつなげるだけです。
`main.js` で `require` している部分は削除し、`main.js` の前に `clone.js` の内容が来るように結合します。

```sh
cat ./node_modules/clone/clone.js main.js > all.js
```

そして、結合したファイルをブラウザから読み込みます。

```html
<script src="all.js"></script>
```

これで実行されるスクリプトは、`<script>` で個別に読み込んだ場合と一緒です。
これをわざわざ行なう目的は、リクエスト数を減らして性能を改善する事にあります。
HTTP/2 が普及すれば必要無くなる事かも知れません。

#### `require` を理解するツールで結合する

上記の単純な方法だと、`require` を削除した上で順番などにも配慮して結合しなければいけません。
そこで作られたのが、Browserify などのツールです。
`require` を理解し、うまく動くように単純な結合以上の事をやってくれます。
`require` が使えるという事は、ブラウザ用の JavaScript のコードを Node.js 用と同じに出来ますし、各ファイルの依存関係がコードに表現される、という点で便利です。

> ```
> browserify main.js -o bundle.js
> ```
>
> ・出力されたbundle.jsを読み込んだら、望む結果を取得できました
>   ・毎回このような処理が必要なのでしょうか？

そういう事になります。
このような毎回の作業を効率化する物として、Gulp などのビルドツールがあります。

Comment: 「npm で配布されているパッケージの中にはブラウザでは動かない物もありますので、そこは確認が必要です。また、ブラウザで動かす際はプロジェクトページや README に方法の記述があれば、まずはそれに従うのが無難でしょう」。なるほど、npm におけるブラウザとはそういう位置づけなのですね。大変参考になりました